# Highcharts - Stacked bar chart - Remove axis

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to remove axis from the stacked bar char.

I've tried `exporting: { enabled: false },` but it didnt work ?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hB2nK/)

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Here it is

```
xAxis: {
            tickWidth: 0,
            lineWidth:0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels:{
                enabled:false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: ''
            },
            tickWidth: 0,
            lineWidth:0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels:{
                enabled:false
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
           enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
           enabled: false
        }
    },
```